# Failed to connect to: ip : Previous connection attempts failed, server blacklisted mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to store the data of a gearman worker in mongodb.

Basically this is what my function does

```
workerfunction() 
{
    // connect to mongo and check if the data is already processed
    if data {
        return data
    } else {
        // process and store in mongo
    }
}
```

I have around 20 workers running in parallel. Mongodb is stopping the connection. I have noticed ulimit http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/monitoring/

How could we resolve this situation?

Comment: I'm not familiar with GearMan -- but you might be hitting a connection pool limit depending on how your code is being executed. What server "blacklisted" Mongodb?

Comment: @WiredPrairie that is what the error is got in http://genghisapp.com/ . When you look into ps -aux | grep mongo there is none. So needed to start the service mongodb again.

Comment: Did you look in the log to see why MongoDB is crashing?

Comment: I don't see any reason for the crash :( .

Comment: Nothing at all in the logs at the time of the crash?

Comment: @WiredPrairie Only the last queries that ran are there. Nothing else I noticed.